# Why is psuedo class before span causing span to move down

Tags: html, css

Hi I was trying to get three textboxes with labels. The third text box was going to be the sum of the first two textboxes.

```css
label {
    display:block;
}
span {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

input {
    width:50px;
}

#total:before {
    content: "=";
    position: relative;
    top: 21px;
    left: -34px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>
        <label>Geeks</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <label>Nerds</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </span>
    <span id="total">
        <label>Total</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </span>
</div>
```

The problem is that in trying to position the equals sign in line with the textbox the whole span has moved down with it. Can anybody tell me how to get the equals to move down but leave the textbox where it is.

I've tried position absolute but the equals disappears.

Comment: Use `float: left;` for pseudo element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `before` element is still in the document flow. Only `float: left/right` and `position:absolute/fixed` take an element out of the flow. Just add a `float:left` property to take it out of the flow. The actual position is still controlled by the `position` properties.

```css
label {
    display:block;
}
span {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

input {
    width:50px;
}

#total:before {
    content: "=";
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    top: 21px;
    left: -34px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>
        <label>Geeks</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <label>Nerds</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </span>
    <span id="total">
        <label>Total</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6um5hk2g/

```
label {
    display:block;
}
span {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

input {
    width:50px;
}

#total:before {
    content: "=";
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 21px;
    left: -34px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#total:before {
content: "=";
position: absolute;
top: 21px;
left: -34px;
} 
#total{
position: relative;
}
```

Could do the trick.